# HTML snippet - Stack Overflow flair creates error in blogger

Tags: bug, flair, design, xml

In the template editor of Blogger, when I try to insert the HTML flair snippet I get the following error:

> Error parsing XML, line 1000, column 3: The element type "img" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "`</img>`".

XML, in contrast to HTML needs an `<opening>` and a `<closing>` tag unless the element is `</empty>`. So I guess for some reason it interprets the HTML snippet into XML and gives back a well-formedness error.

Alright, the fix is obvious. Nonetheless, I would like to know why this happened. Is it intended, a known bug or what?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you asking if this is a bug in Blogger? In that case, we would have no idea here.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in Blogger i wouldn't know either.That's why i asked in the first place. Anyway i though of it as something worth mentioning in the Meta in case someone is interested.

Comment: The image tag is indeed invalid and not well formed. if you paste this to the flair snippet you still get error? (note the "/" character) `<img src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1834437.png" width="208" height="58" alt="profile for LDN-5602 at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers" title="profile for LDN-5602 at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers" />`

Comment: Nope, `<img various_attributes />` resolves the problem.